# User defined search of a hash

Tags: perl, search, hash, user-defined

New to Perl. Using Windows 10 w/ Padre IDE. I have a question that has been stumping me and it's probably very simple yet I have yet to find an answer on the net.

Here is the code that is working up until my search. It reads a list.txt file with names and matching phone numbers so I have two hashes (one is name => number, the second is number =>).

```
my $search = "";

print "File name to be read in: ";
my $textFile = <>;

open FILE, $textFile;
my %hash;

while (<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split / /;

    $hash{$key} .= exists $hash{$key} ? "$val" : $val;
}

close FILE;

open FILE, $textFile;
my %hash2;

while (<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    my ($val, $key) = split / /;

    $hash2{$key} .= exists $hash2{$key} ? "$val" : $val;
}

close FILE;


print "(N) for name (#) for number search and (.) to exit: ";

$search = <>;

if ($search == "N")                #heres where we have the problem
{
        print "Enter name: ";  
        my $person = <>;           #user defined search looks for Bob Smith
        print $hash{$person};      #prints nothing
}
```

However, when I make the search non-user defined, it works perfected as in:

```
if ($search == "N")                
{
        #print "Enter name: ";  
        #my $person = <>;           
        print $hash{"Bob Smith"};      #prints Bob Smith's number
}
```

For the record, I had $search print to screen to verify that there was no issue whenI entered the name in the first place. When I user-define the search, the hash will not pull up. When the name is specically coded into the hash function, it works every time.

Thank you for helping a stumped Perl Noobie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a trailing newline character.  You need to [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) before you compare:

```
$search = <>;
chomp $search;
```

Also, you should use the string compare `eq`:

```
if ($search eq "N")
```